# Why is printf() printing out in this code?

Tags: c, printf

This simple code is puzzling me - I am deliberately printing out more integers than I passed to printf.  I expected an error.  I got weird numbers - where are they coming from?

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* learn arrays */
void main(){
    int pout;
    pout = 6;
    printf("%i %i %i\n%i %i %i\n%i %i %i\n", pout);
}
```

One example of the output:

```
6 608728840 0
-885621664 -885543392 608728816
0 0 -889304251
```

The single digits do not change with repeated runs, but the large integers do.

Comment: I don't understand why it was downvoted. This is a real question, and without knowing anything about printf format string, a duplicate is hard to find.

Comment: @Mr.ST4N question should be downvoted when, on a personal judgment, they do not show enough research, are incomplete or badly written, or simply you think they do not deserve that some person spends time to answer them (the questions with more votes will rise to the top and the ones downvoted will sink to the bottom). You upvote them if you think they are well written, interesting, not too specific (and thus more likely to be useful to future readers of the site). Again, the right to vote is yours and you can use it however you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's one of printf string format vulnerability. You are trying to call more argument than there actually are, so printf takes whatever he can on the stack.

It was (and still is) very used to exploit programs into exploring stacks to access hidden information or bypass authentication for example.

> Viewing the stack
>
> ```
> printf ("%08x %08x %08x %08x %08x\n");
> ```
>
> This
>   instructs the printf-function to retrieve five parameters from the
>   stack and display them as 8-digit padded hexadecimal numbers. So a
>   possible output may look like:
>
> `40012980 080628c4 bffff7a4 00000005 08059c04`

See [this](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: You downvoted my answer when no one wanted to downvote yours. Your answer might be a fact but it's wrong. That is not the answer, you are just exposing something you know. But the answer is it's undefined behavior. What actually happens is irrelevant. Because the standard didn't specify the behavior in this case. Whether your *exploit* would work or not, it's a matter of luck, because the behavior will be different in different situations when it's not defined.

Comment: You ask yourself how I know that **you** downvoted my answer. The answer is math.

Comment: OP is asking where the numbers are coming from, and what's actually happening. Your answer is not wrong but incomplete. This is the only reason I downvoted it, not because  mine wasn't upvoted nor downvoted. :)

Comment: Yes, I know that my reputation lowers when downvoting. If you really think I should remove my downvote after these comments, tell me and I'll do it.

Comment: It's not possible to explain that, because the fact is that undefined behavior happened. You need to understand that undefined behavior is very common and many programmers don't know what it is or it's origin. Your answer is almost telling that there is a defined behavior that you can control. The standard says it's undefined. You can see that I downvoted your answer because of that, initially I upvoted it then you edited it and I changed my mind.

Comment: No, don't remove anything. Please be open to discussion. It's one of the things I love about SO. I've learned so much when I give wrong answers. Your answer is not really wrong, it's just that you had to mention about undefined behavior and how a side effect of making that mistake would be used against you.

Comment: I am open, I'll just learn not to downvote so quickly next time :)

Comment: @Mr.ST4N downvote is supposed to be used to remove wrong and potentially dangerous (because people may do mistakes by following them) questions. If the answer is valid albeit lacking some information or even wrong but not dangerous (because it can be easily understood that it is wrong) it is not worth it to spend your reputation in downvoting it. That said, it is only _you_ who should decide how to vote

Comment: This answer is correct, but you forget that read memory like that can make your program sigsev, it's why it is an "undefined behaviour". You must not use printf to do that :P

Answer (score 5):

Because it's undefined behavior. If the number of specifiers is larger than the number of matching parameters or their types are incompatible, the behavior is undefined.

This qoute is from the c11 standard draft

> **7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function**
>
> 2. The `fprintf` function writes output to the stream pointed to by stream, under control of the string pointed to by format that specifies how subsequent arguments are converted for output. **If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined**. If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored. The fprintf function returns when the end of the format string is encountered.
>
> ---
>
> 9. If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>282)</sup> **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**.

I highlighted the relevant parts making them bold.

Comment: to translate that into human speak, when some construct in C or C++ has undefined behaviour, anything may happen including alien kidnapping your children, and it will be your fault, not the compiler's. Most compilers however will have the program do some less exoteric behaviour, like the one described in @Mr.St4N 's answer.

Comment: done, so that people will not be confused to think it is the same language

Answer (score 0):

The int reserves some RAM but you didn't wrote anything in so it shows you what numbers are random somewhere in your RAM